# ¿cómo mostrar producto y multiples imagenes correctamente con php y mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

hace un buen rato me estoy rompiendo la cabeza sobre como hacer esto de la forma correcta, no tuve problemas en el armado de la base de datos ni en mostrar un determinado producto con todas sus imagenes (en php), lo que me genera dudas es si lo estoy haciendo de la forma correcta, ya que hago la consulta a la base de datos que es la siguiente:

SELECT p.id as id_producto, titulo,descripcion,precio,ruta
FROM productos p
JOIN imagenes i
ON i.id_producto = p.id
JOIN galeria g
ON g.id = i.id_galeria
WHERE p.id = 1

hasta ahi barbaro, cuando obtengo todos los datos en php, hago un print_r() y obtengo esto:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id_producto] => 1
        [0] => 1
        [titulo] => parlante philips
        [1] => parlante philips
        [descripcion] => parlante philips extra bass
        [2] => parlante philips extra bass
        [precio] => 1500
        [3] => 1500
        [ruta] => https://images.philips.com/is/image/PhilipsConsumer/CSP630_00-IMS-es_AR?$jpglarge$&wid=1250
        [4] => https://images.philips.com/is/image/PhilipsConsumer/CSP630_00-IMS-es_AR?$jpglarge$&wid=1250
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id_producto] => 1
        [0] => 1
        [titulo] => parlante philips
        [1] => parlante philips
        [descripcion] => parlante philips extra bass
        [2] => parlante philips extra bass
        [precio] => 1500
        [3] => 1500
        [ruta] => http://www.vitepal.cl/imageDB/CSP1200.jpg
        [4] => http://www.vitepal.cl/imageDB/CSP1200.jpg
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id_producto] => 1
        [0] => 1
        [titulo] => parlante philips
        [1] => parlante philips
        [descripcion] => parlante philips extra bass
        [2] => parlante philips extra bass
        [precio] => 1500
        [3] => 1500
        [ruta] => http://mla-s1-p.mlstatic.com/parlantes-audio-486511-MLA20578733894_022016-Y.jpg
        [4] => http://mla-s1-p.mlstatic.com/parlantes-audio-486511-MLA20578733894_022016-Y.jpg
    )
```

)

es decir, obtengo todos los datos correctamente, pero al haber 3 imagenes para un mismo producto, me trae 3 veces todos los datos del producto, cosa que no me termina de parecer lo mas correcto, ya que lo unico que necesito es que me traiga 1 sola vez los datos del producto, y las 3 imagenes.

Hay alguna forma de hacer esto que pido en una sola consulta? o debería hacer una consulta para traer los datos y otra aparte para traer las imagenes, y ahi hacer un foreach para que muestre todas?

muchas gracias, espero respuesta!

Comment: Sí, te sugiero que lo hagas en dos pasos como ya describiste en uno los datos y en otra las imágenes. Éxito.

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta, lo hice de esa forma y ya me trae los datos de la forma que necesitaba!

Answer (score 0):

La mejor forma sería depurar la consulta con "LEFT JOIN" [Todos los tipos de Join en SQL](https://ingenieriadesoftware.es/tipos-sql-join-guia-referencia/)

[image: Esquema SQL JOINS]

---

**Otra solución...**

O bien si te encuentras con un array así lo puedes depurar de la siguiente manera:

```
    <?php

$producto[0] = Array
    (
        "id_producto" => 1,
        0 => 1,
        "titulo" => "parlante philips",
        1 => "parlante philips",
        "descripcion" => "parlante philips extra bass",
        2 => "parlante philips extra bass",
        "precio" => 1500,
        3 => 1500,
        "ruta" => 'https://images.philips.com/is/image/PhilipsConsumer/CSP630_00-IMS-es_AR?$jpglarge$&wid=1250',
        4 => 'https://images.philips.com/is/image/PhilipsConsumer/CSP630_00-IMS-es_AR?$jpglarge$&wid=1250'
    );

$producto[1] = Array
    (
      "id_producto" => 1,
      0 => 1,
      "titulo" => "parlante philips",
      1 => "parlante philips",
      "descripcion" => "parlante philips extra bass",
      2 => "parlante philips extra bass",
      "precio" => 1500,
      3 => 1500,
      "ruta" => "http://www.vitepal.cl/imageDB/CSP1200.jpg",
        4 => "http://www.vitepal.cl/imageDB/CSP1200.jpg"
    );

$producto[2] = Array
    (
      "id_producto" => 1,
      0 => 1,
      "titulo" => "parlante philips",
      1 => "parlante philips",
      "descripcion" => "parlante philips extra bass",
      2 => "parlante philips extra bass",
      "precio" => 1500,
      3 => 1500,
      "ruta" => "http://mla-s1-p.mlstatic.com/parlantes-audio-486511-MLA20578733894_022016-Y.jpg",
        4 => "http://mla-s1-p.mlstatic.com/parlantes-audio-486511-MLA20578733894_022016-Y.jpg"
    );




    $product_imgs = array();
    $x = 0;
    $n = 0;

    foreach($producto as $name => $value) {
        foreach($value as $name2 => $value2)  {

            if((string)$name2 == 'ruta' || (string)$name2 == 4 ) {
              $product_imgs[$n][$name2] = $value2;
              $x++;
            }

            if($x == 2) {
              $n++;
              $x = 0;
            }
        }
  }
unset($producto[0]['ruta']);
unset($producto[0][4]);

$producto[0]['images'] = $product_imgs;

var_dump($producto[0]);

 ?>
```

**Resultado...**

```
 array (size=9)
  'id_producto' => int 1
  0 => int 1
  'titulo' => string 'parlante philips' (length=16)
  1 => string 'parlante philips' (length=16)
  'descripcion' => string 'parlante philips extra bass' (length=27)
  2 => string 'parlante philips extra bass' (length=27)
  'precio' => int 1500
  3 => int 1500
  'images' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'ruta' => string 'https://images.philips.com/is/image/PhilipsConsumer/CSP630_00-IMS-es_AR?$jpglarge$&wid=1250' (length=91)
          4 => string 'https://images.philips.com/is/image/PhilipsConsumer/CSP630_00-IMS-es_AR?$jpglarge$&wid=1250' (length=91)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'ruta' => string 'http://www.vitepal.cl/imageDB/CSP1200.jpg' (length=41)
          4 => string 'http://www.vitepal.cl/imageDB/CSP1200.jpg' (length=41)
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          'ruta' => string 'http://mla-s1-p.mlstatic.com/parlantes-audio-486511-MLA20578733894_022016-Y.jpg' (length=79)
          4 => string 'http://mla-s1-p.mlstatic.com/parlantes-audio-486511-MLA20578733894_022016-Y.jpg' (length=79)
```